# MySQL case sensitive table names on Linux

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, linux, mysql-5.1, case-sensitive

Moving a MySQL database from Windows to Linux I have the problem that on Linux the names of the tables are case sensitive. This is a problem, because the Java application that I am developing can't find tables.

I have changed my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file adding the row:

`lower_case_table_names=1`

But that did not change anything.

My server version is:
`5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1 (Ubuntu)`

How can I configure MySQL to ignore case in table names?

Comment: I find the most sounding solution to this issue is to write all table names case-sensitive in the code!

Comment: @Neveroldmilk that would be nonstandard: future developers expect that sql in not case sensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just altering the lower_case_table_names setting isn't enough.  It needs to be done before you import your database(s).

The [MySQL 5.1 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) lists a procedure for moving between Windows and Linux/UNIX.  This will ensure that your desired rules for enforcing case sensitivity are followed.  Take a look and verify that you did these steps in the correct order:

> To convert one or more entire databases, dump them before setting
>   lower_case_table_names, then drop the databases, and reload them after
>   setting lower_case_table_names:
>
> 1 - Use mysqldump to dump each database:
>
> mysqldump --databases db1 > db1.sql
>
> mysqldump --databases db2 >
>   db2.sql
>
> ... Do this for each database that must be recreated.
>
> 2 - Use DROP DATABASE to drop each database.
>
> 3 - Stop the server, set `lower_case_table_names` in the `[mysqld]` section of your `\etc\mysql\my.cnf` file, and restart the server.
>
> 4 - Reload the dump file for each database. Because lower_case_table_names
>   is set, each database and table name will be converted to lowercase as
>   it is recreated:
>
> mysql < db1.sql
>
> mysql < db2.sql

Comment: Does `mysqldump` do a perfect dump? Will any of the data change if we export-drop-import?

Answer (score -1):

File in etc/my.cnf
Find this # The MySQL server [mysqld]
and set lower_case_table_names = 1

There is no need to drop db. It works so first check with this.
Reason is default value of lower_case_table_names =1 for Windows.